# Disabling shading underneath a (discrete) probability mass function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot a hypergeometric probability mass function for a discrete random variable X with the following code:

```
# Hypergeometric Distribution code adapted from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import hypergeom, norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# (N, K, n) The hypergeometric distribution models drawing objects from a bin. N is the total number of objects, K is total number of Type I objects. The random variate represents the number of Type I objects in n drawn without replacement from the total population.
[N, K, n] = [2000, 278, 500]
rv1 = hypergeom(N, K, n) 
x = np.arange(0, n+1)
pmf1 = rv1.pmf(x)

xlabel="Number of people who are interested"; ylabel="Probability of event (PMF)"
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(x, pmf1, 'bo:', aa=True)
ax1.vlines(x, 0, pmf1, lw=2); ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel); ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel)
```

As per the original code from [Scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html), I expected it to generate a stem plot, as from their website's picture below:

[image]

However the actual plot I get is like this (note the blue shading underneath the graph)
[image]

When I decrease the range of the x-axis using `ax1.set_xlim(left=None, right=200)`, it displays the same behaviour: blue shading underneath the graph. However, if I reduce the parameters of the distribution from `[N, K, n] = [2000, 278, 500]` to `[200, 30, 50]`, it reverts back to the behaviour as displayed in the first image from Matplotlib's website.

My questions:

1. Why does this behaviour occur when the parameters used in the hypergeometric distribution are large, and
2. How can I remove the blue shading underneath the graph?
3. Also, is it possible to remove the 'stems' in the first picture connecting the data points to the x-axis?

Note: I am using Jupyter Notebooks in VSCode, if that is a factor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the n to make the lines visible like so (this only depends on `n` which is the discrete variable of interest (people in your example, dogs in the scipy docs; if sufficiently large this becomes a solid area):

```
[N, K, n] = [2000, 278, 100]
```

which produces

[image]

Also, just remove `ax1.vlines(x, 0, pmf1, lw=2);` which produces

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about the function of the ```ax.vlines()``` piece inside the tutorial code. Thanks!